# Cypress: Page does not open

Tags: cypress, laravel-10

I have the following problem, when I run the test I get the following error message:

Sorry, we could not load:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard
500 - Internal Server Error (text/html)

but the URL is correct: http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard

Do you have a tip?

```
describe('Visit Dashboard', () => {
    it('check', () => {
        cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard')
        cy.url().should('include', 'dashboard')
    })
})
```

Comment: When u just open url http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard it is Ok? Content is visible, no problem here?

Comment: The URL ist OK...